# Vim Text object and parentheses

Tags: vimrc, object-motions

I have a trouble with text objects and parentheses.
For example with this sentence:
`<bla bla="test">(hello)</bla>`

With the cursor at the beginning of the line, when I use `ci"` ("change inner double quote") the cursor jumps properly in the double quotes and erases the content in the double quote.

But if I do `ci(`, it doesn't work. It requires me to jump on the parenthesis (or in the parentheses) before it changes the content `f(ci(`.

Is it a bug? Is there some customization to do in `vimrc`?

I am on Windows, VIM 7.4.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14651443/546861